# Loading bitmap from internet in ImageView using Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to load an image from internet in ImageView using this code:

```
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String bitmapUrl) {
      try {
        URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);               
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {             
        return null;
      }
}
```

It works fine with Android 2+ but fails on Ice Cream Sandwich, no errors, the image is just not displayed (I'm using the emulator btw). Any ideas what's the problem is?...thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

I was getting an NetworkOnMainThreadException and I forgot print the error in catch (yeah, my bad!), so the problem is I was using the code within a sub-activyty and since Honeycomb is not possible to perform a networking operation on the main thread a handler or asynctask must be used.